# Spawning a number of enemies in random but different locations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a space game where you shoot incoming asteroids. These asteroids are spawned with a c# script that allows me to spawn a set amount of enemies at the same time. 
The spawn locations are random for the x-value between 2 int numbers, but with my current script some enemies spawn on each other and I cannot figure out how I can make each enemy spawn on a different location.
Here's my attempt, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public int spawnCount; //number of asteroids that are spawned
public Vector3 location;
public GameObject asteroid;   
for (int i = 0; i < spawnCount; i++) 
    {
        int locationGiver = 0;
        int[] ChosenLocations = new int[]; 
          //Create an array to store previous chosen locations
                int RandomLocation = Random.Range (-6, 6);
                for(int l = 0; l < ChosenLocations.Length ;l++)
                { 
            //Check if RandomLocation is not the same as any previously determined       locations
                    if(ChosenLocations[l] == RandomLocation)
                    {
                        RandomLocation = Random.Range (-6, 6);
                        l = 0;
              //if it is the same, choose a new location and check if that one is  different
                    }
                }
                location = new Vector3(RandomLocation, 0, 17);
    //use the generated x value to create a location
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    //gives a random rotation to the asteroids, can be ignored
                Instantiate (asteroid, location, spawnRotation);
    //spawns the asteroid at the determined location
                ChosenLocations[locationGiver] = RandomLocation;
                locationGiver++;
    //save the x-value in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to specify the size of the ChosenLocations array.  As written, your line initializing the array will not compile.  If the size is intended to be dynamic, then you need to use another type, like a list.

For the sake of solving the problem, let's assume your array is of size 10.

Try something like this:

```
int[] ChosenLocations = new int[10];
bool match;
Random r = new Random(); //I am using the .NET random generator, since I don't have Unity3d
for (int l = 0; l < ChosenLocations.Length; l++)
{
    match = true;
    while (match)
    {
        int RandomLocation = r.Next(-6, 7);    
        if (!ChosenLocations.Contains(RandomLocation))
        {
            match = false;
            ChosenLocations[l] = RandomLocation;
            // Instantiate your asteroids here...
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Location {0}: {1}", l, ChosenLocations[l]));
         }
   }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hey, I replaced my code with yours but now unity completely freezes just as it gets to the 1st spawn. I left everything intact (except for the .net random generator since i'm using unity) and added the code to spawn the objects.

Comment: I don't know anything about unity.  I was only trying to solve your logic problem of how to choose random numbers without repeats.  You may need to ask another question about unity. But if you look at my code carefully, you will notice that the spawning part either needs to happen inside the while loop or in a separate foreach loop that cycles through each unit of the ChosenLocations array.  I did not restructure the spawning part of your code; that's up to you. Try debugging your code to see what exactly is happening when the spawning crashes.

Comment: Another possibility (since you said unity freezes) is that you are stuck in an endless while loop.  That will happen if your maximum number of asteroids is larger than the number of possible locations.